# windows remote desktop connection wont connect to ubuntu server

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I am using Ubuntu 22.10. I am trying to connect to the Ubuntu server from my Windows device using Windows Remote Desktop Connection.

On the Ubuntu server I have done the following

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install xrdp

sudo systemctl enable xrdp

sudo ufw allow 3389/tcp

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop

reboot
```

xrdp is enabled, TCP connections are allowed on port 3389 and Ubuntu-Desktop is installed.

I now open Windows Remote Desktop Connection, put in the IP to connect to but get an error saying the Windows cant connect to the remote computer. The only suggestions are to check that the remote computer is turned on, which it is, and that it is on the network which it is, and that it accepts remote connections which I think it does? How else do I troubleshoot?

I am able to access using SSH.

What do I need to do to be able to connect with Windows Remote Desktop Connection? Or how else do I access the ubuntu desktop instead of using SSH?

Thanks

Edit

Added out put from  `sudo systemctl status xrdp`

```
● xrdp.service - xrdp daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/xrdp.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2023-01-07 22:59:05 UTC; 1min 2s ago
       Docs: man:xrdp(8)
             man:xrdp.ini(5)
    Process: 2278 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh /usr/share/xrdp/socksetup (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 2286 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/xrdp $XRDP_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 2287 (xrdp)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9485)
     Memory: 864.0K
        CPU: 20ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/xrdp.service
             └─2287 /usr/sbin/xrdp

Jan 07 22:59:04 ubuntu-london systemd[1]: Starting xrdp daemon...
Jan 07 22:59:04 ubuntu-london xrdp[2286]: [INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389] mode 1
Jan 07 22:59:04 ubuntu-london xrdp[2286]: [INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0
Jan 07 22:59:04 ubuntu-london xrdp[2286]: [INFO ] xrdp_listen_pp done
Jan 07 22:59:04 ubuntu-london systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Can't open PID file /run/xrdp/xrdp.pid (yet?) after start: Operation not permitted
Jan 07 22:59:05 ubuntu-london systemd[1]: Started xrdp daemon.
Jan 07 22:59:06 ubuntu-london xrdp[2287]: [INFO ] starting xrdp with pid 2287
Jan 07 22:59:06 ubuntu-london xrdp[2287]: [INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389] mode 1
Jan 07 22:59:06 ubuntu-london xrdp[2287]: [INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0
Jan 07 22:59:06 ubuntu-london xrdp[2287]: [INFO ] xrdp_listen_pp done
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
lines 1-24/24 (END)
```

Comment: This site suggests a polkit file in etc is necessary. Did you check if xserver is running, install rdp client on same box and try connecting internally first.

Comment: try typing this in to the terminal of your ubuntu desktop: ufw allow 3389/tcp also be sure windows network connection is in private mode

Comment: Hi, I have put 'ufw allow 3389/tcp', which hasnt changed anything. How can I check if windows connection is in private mode?

Comment: Windows 10/11 go to settings/network and internet/select the active connection

Comment: also can you post the output of:     sudo systemctl status xrdp

Comment: Ive added output in original post.